# jquery function to emulate css background-size: cover using an img and also fading img when loaded

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

OK, I am here for some real expert help, as what I've tried is not working :(

Basically, I would like to use jQuery to replicate exactly what background-size: cover does with an image inside an div.

I am trying to get the cross in the image to always stay center. Also once the image has faded it, if the browser resizes I would like it not fade in again.

I've tried updating scripts like this but I am having no luck...

```
.pane {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    overflow:hidden;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}

var imgRatio;
$("img").load(function(){
    var $i = $(this);
    imgRatio = $i.width()/$i.height();
    var $w = $(window);
    $w.on("resize",function(){
        $i.css("min-width",$w.height() * imgRatio);
    }).resize();
});
```

See fiddle with above script.

http://jsfiddle.net/wmnWc/16/

See this fiddle below which shows you what I'm trying emulate, but I need an image fade when the background image loads, which I can't do with this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/wmnWc/17/

Can any one help me out?

The reason I am trying to do this is because I want to fade the image in when loaded which I can't do with background-size. And also for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `min-width` just use `width`.

`$i.css("width",$w.height() * imgRatio);`

**EDIT**: [Demo with fade](http://jsfiddle.net/U9mPL/)

Comment: That leaves white spaces, I need it to look like this and also fade in when loaded... http://jsfiddle.net/wmnWc/17/

Comment: @Joshc why not use CSS3 for the fade in animation? http://graphicfusiondesign.com/blog/design/creating-fancy-css3-fade-in-animations-on-page-load/

Comment: @Joshc look at the demo I added to my answer and see if is it that you want

Comment: @Joshua Smickus I love the CSS 3 animations

Comment: @zeta thanks for your comments, going to use all css3 now with a jquery fall ball for IE